# CSS transition doesn't animate when immediately changing size via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, css-animations

When setting the height of an element to 0 in JavaScript and then immediately changing it to a specific value, the CSS transition for the element doesn't work.

However, by placing the code to increase the height inside a `setTimeout()`, even with a delay of 0, the transition works, as you can see in the following snippet:

```js
// Doesn't work:
document.getElementById("one").setAttribute("style", "height: 0px");
document.getElementById("one").setAttribute("style", "height: 200px");

// Works:
document.getElementById("two").setAttribute("style", "height: 0px");
setTimeout(function() {
 document.getElementById("two").setAttribute("style", "height: 200px");
}, 0);
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  transition: height 1s;
}

#two {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
</div>
<div id="two">
</div>
```

This behavior is consistent across all major browsers. The problem with this is, that *sometimes*, there seems to be some kind of lag, which makes the workaround not animate as well. So this doesn't seem to be a clean solution.

What causes the transition to cancel and how can I get around this cleanly?

Comment: `setTimeout(..., 0)` ain't really a `0` timeout, but rather more like a `setTimeout(..., asSoonAsYouHaveTimeForThatButAtLeast(10))`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most likely browsers optimize transitions and will merge changes which take less than 16ms (which would get you a refresh rate of about 60 frames per second)

So the solution is to simply wrap style changes nested RAF calls (tell the browser to animate when it's ready rather than after an arbitrary timeout)

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
document.getElementById("two").setAttribute("style", "height: 0px");
 window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
    document.getElementById("two").setAttribute("style", "height:  200px");
  });
});
```

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: you have to nest these two function-calls or both functions will be called on the same animation frame, and therefore the styles will be merged again.

Comment: Nesting the RAFs did the trick. @Tudor Ilisoi I will gladly mark your answer as accepted once you have corrected it.

Comment: @SimonMathewson, Tudor, you don't need to wait at all, you can [force the browser into a render-cycle](//stackoverflow.com/a/41408188/6567275), right in the middle of your code. This might be handy or pretty expensive, depending on how you use it.

Comment: @Thomas Thank you, but the solution you are suggesting only applies to the height property and, as you have already stated, is power-expensive. The solution Tudor suggested, with your correction, can be used in more cases and seems more intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it to the `window.onload` event

```
window.addEventListener("load", init, false);

function init() {
    document.getElementById("one").style.height = "200px";
}
```

also you gonna have to set `#one` height in CSS to `0`

```
#one {
   height:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//cache the object in a variable
var one = document.getElementById("one");

//do you really need to overwrite all stlyles defined on this object?
//if not, prefer style-property over attribute
//set animation-start
one.style.height = 0;

//force the browser to apply styles
getComputedStyles(one);

//apply the animation-target
one.style.height = "200px";
```

You don't need any timeout, but beware, this forces the browser into a render-cycle (one of the most expensive things one could do in JS).

So don't use this in a loop (or on multiple nodes, one after the other).
But instead do two loops, first set all the start-values, force the browser into the render-cycle, and then apply all the target-values.

Comment: What exactly is `one.scrollHeight;` doing?

Comment: @SimonMathewson it's asking the browser for a value, basically `doNothingWith(one.scrollHeight)`. To properly answer this request, the browser has to apply pending style changes first *(because `style.height = 0` may have changes the scrollHeight)*. And that is basically a render-cycle (although it might not refresh the screen). Now `style.height = '200px'` is a pending style marked for the *next* render-cycle to be applied, and therefore they don't get merged.