# Can I Maintain CSS Transitions Even if I'm Switching Which Properties I'm Using?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, transition

I have a div that I'm moving around left to right. In order for it to always be on-screen and never misaligned if the window is resized, I switch my use of `left` and `right` depending on which side of the screen is closest.

What happens is that the CSS transition I have for changing the left and right properties works smoothly so long as the user is moving the div back and forth on the same side of the screen (that is to say, the div is remaining oriented towards the same property) but as soon as the orientation switches from left to right or vice versa, there is no transition and the div just moves instantly.

How can I maintain the CSS transition I have (or a similar one that I don't have) even when switching between using left and right?

I have this function in javascript:

```
function moveTimeline(screenIndex) {
    // possibly variable because of window resize
    let timelineSectionWidth = (TIMELINE_BACKGROUND_WIDTH - documentElement.clientWidth) / num_timelinePieces;
    // check what side the div is supposed to be attached to
    let isOnLeftSide = (screenIndex < num_timelinePieces / 2);
    // reverse the index if it's on the right side
    if (!isOnLeftSide)
        screenIndex = screenIndex - num_timelinePieces;
    // calculate new pixel position
    let new_timelinePosition = Math.floor(screenIndex * timelineSectionWidth);

    // unset the unused properties so they don't interfere
    if (isOnLeftSide) {
        timelineBackground.css({
            "left": "-" + new_timelinePosition + "px",
            "right": "auto"
        });
    } else {
        timelineBackground.css({
            "left": "auto",
            "right": (new_timelinePosition) + "px"
        });
    }
}
```

and this property for the css:

```
transition: left 1s ease, right 1s ease;
```

I was hoping for the div to continue moving smoothly from left to right even when switching which property is on `auto`pilot but that didn't end up working. Not sure how to proceed from here. I'd really rather not use a single property since that can mess up the div's position if the window is resized, and manually moving the div step by step is an absolute last resort.

Comment: You can not transition to or from `auto`. I suppose you would have to get the actual current left or right position of the element, explicitly _set_ that as the left/right value, and then set your new position afterwards, so that it can transition from that one pixel value to the other. Of course you will have to introduce a "break" between setting the two values, otherwise there will be no transition at all.

Comment: What do you mean by "introducing a break"? I also considered this but I wasn't sure how to get the `right` value if I wasn't using it in the first place and it would have no real value... unless I'm mistaken?

Comment: Regarding "introducing a break", see https://stackoverflow.com/q/41407861/1427878 _"wasn't sure how to get the right value if I wasn't using it in the first place"_ - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Answer (score 0):

The reason your transition seems to `snap` over to the other side when you switch from right to left is because you are setting `left` and `right` to `auto` value. CSS transitions (or just CSS animations in general) don't work on props with `auto` values.

This is from the docs on [Using CSS Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_transitions/Using_CSS_transitions#which_css_properties_can_be_transitioned):

> The `auto` value is often a very complex case. The **specification recommends not animating from and to** `auto`. Some user agents, like those based on Gecko, implement this requirement and others, like those based on WebKit, are less strict. Using animations with `auto` may lead to unpredictable results, depending on the browser and its version, and should be avoided.

Maybe you would be better off using the `transform` CSS property with the `translateX()` function instead of `left/right` CSS props? Doing this would give you a single, reliable, CSS value to transition, and be more performant.

Your code might look something like this:

```js
function moveTimeline(screenIndex) {

  ...

  if (isOnLeftSide) {
      timelineBackground.css({
         "transform": `translateX(-${new_timelinePosition}px)`
      });
  } else {
      timelineBackground.css({
          "transform": `translateX(${new_timelinePosition}px)`
      });
  }
}
```

And your CSS transition would look like this:

```css
transition: transform 1s ease;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is interesting. I'll try using this in conjunction with setting the left and right properties so it can still be anchored. Thank you for the input.

Comment: I thought of suggesting `translateX` as well, but that is probably not going to help with the problem of keeping things in the viewport when the size changes. Having the element positioned at either, say, 25px from left or right, will keep it in the viewport in almost any case, but if you were to position the element in the middle initially, and then moved it to the left or right using a larger negative or positive `translateX` value, the problem of it "disappearing" when the viewport width gets smaller, would still be present.

Comment: Unsure why the topic of keeping it in the viewport is here, but happy to discuss. Could probably be solved with intersection observer, some good ole `isInView` code, and programmatically repositioning the element when it's outside of the view port.

Comment: It's here because that was the reason I was switching using `left` and `right` in the first place. It's not that the div goes out of the viewport, but that if the viewport gets larger, it's possible for the div to stay too far in one direction and leave a large margin between itself and the viewport edge, when it should have been attached. Setting `right: 0` fixes this on the right side, vice versa.